# Is it possible to modify with a formula the same cell where you introduce the value in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

So imagine we have column A, B and C. And I want to sum A1 + B1

You can do type in C1 "=SUM(A1,B1)" and you will see the result in C1
But, is there any way we can introduce the formula in A1 to see the result in A1 after introducing the value in A1?
So basically what I want to do, when you introduce the value in A1, if there is a value in B1, I want this to be add to the A1 but if there is none, I want A1 to be the same.

All of this while I introduce values in column A.

I hope it does makes sense

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK what you ask is not possible with the exception that if there is a value already in a cell you can perform other operands on it. Such as, if in A1 you have the formula `=100` then press the enter key on that cell and edit it with `+100` the cell will be updated to contain the new value `200` allowing further operands as required in the same manner.